# Como desfazer o último push feito no GitHub?

Tags: git, github

Estou tentando aprender Git e no meio dos meus testes fiz um *push* incorreto para o GitHub.

Fiz o *reset* do último *commit* e tentei dar um *push* novamente achando que iria remover o *commit* no GitHub, mas deu um erro:

```
     ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
    error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:Ferreira-Jefferson/StarWarsRepo.git'
    hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
    hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
    hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
    hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Como desfaço de maneira correta o último *push* feito para o GitHub? E como já fiz um *reset*, o que devo fazer agora?

Comment: Vc fez um Pull antes de tentar o novo Push? Primeiro de um "git pull" e depois disso tente fazer o "git push" novamente

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Como você está tentando reescrever o histórico do repositório, o que não é uma boa prática, ao fazer o *push* é necessário utilizar a *flag* `-f`:

```
git push -f
```

Porém o ideal seria você fazer outro *commit* revertendo o que está errado, mas mantendo o histórico. O que pode ser feito da seguinte forma:

- Faça o *pull* das alterações que estão no repositório remoto com `git pull`.
- Em seguida crie um *commit* revertendo as alterações. Caso seja somente o último *commit*, pode utilizar `git revert HEAD^`.
- Após isso faça o *push* normalmente sem a *flag* `-f`.

Comment: Porém o ideal seria você fazer outro commit revertendo o que está errado, mas mantendo o histórico

...verdade, até porque este é o propósito do Git
Obrigado pela Resposta!